# Display express-session data in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express, authentication

I implemented an OpenID passport.js strategy (passport-steam http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-steam/)

to my MERN-stack app. The logged-in user's information is being saved in an express-session. So the object with the user info is accessible via

```js
req.session.passport.user
```

in my Node.js file.

**What's the best/common approach to make this session-data accessible to my React-frontend?**
In other non-react-projects I've used templating engines like handlebars.js which made it super easy to display properties by passing them like this:

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('main', {
    user: req.user
  });
});
```

also, I don't want to render my react-app on the server-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created an endpoint for the user:

```
app.get("/user", (req, res) => {
res.send(user);
});
```

and fetched the Data in my react app, creating a Conext to make it available to all other Components:

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
const context = createContext(null);

const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
const [user, setUser] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
  fetch("/user")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => setUser(res))
      .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
      });
}, []);

return (
  <context.Provider value={user}>
      {children}
  </context.Provider>
);
};

UserProvider.context = context;
export default UserProvider;
```